ReferenceError: window is not defined when trying to migrate existing Angular application to SSR
We have recently upgraded our application to Angular18 and are exploring SSR. We have successfully executed:
ng add @angular/ssr

However when we launch we get an error in the first component, where we reference the window object:
ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined

I'm not sure how to address this, we have a lot of places where we reference the window object. I've come across:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssr-window
but I'm not sure what to make of this, because exports getWindow, not window.

check the stacktrace and identify which code uses window, then wrap that code inside isPlatFormBrowser you can also use afterRender to solve this.

@NarenMurali Thx, I'm assuming the same  approach applies to other objects that are not available in the backend, i.e. "localstorage".

Yes, if any front end packages use window internally, they need to be imported only on app.module.ts and not on app.server.module.ts
